# Kafka Producer NetworkException and Timeout Exceptions

Tags: java, apache-kafka

We are getting random **`NetworkExceptions`** and **`TimeoutExceptions`** in our production environment:

```
Brokers: 3
Zookeepers: 3
Servers: 3
Kafka: 0.10.0.1
Zookeeeper: 3.4.3
```

We are occasionally getting this exception in my producer logs:

> Expiring 10 record(s) for TOPIC:XXXXXX: 5608 ms has passed since batch
>   creation plus linger time.

Number of milliseconds in such error messages keep changing. Sometimes its *~5 seconds* other times it's up to *~13 seconds*!

And very rarely we get:

```
NetworkException: Server disconnected before response received.
```

Cluster consists of **3** *brokers* and **3** *zookeepers*. Producer server and Kafka cluster are in *same* network.

I am making *synchronous* calls. There's a web service to which multiple user requests call to send their data. Kafka web service has one Producer object which does all the sending. Producer's Request timeout was *1000ms* initially that has been changed to *15000ms* (15 seconds). Even after increasing timeout period **`TimeoutExceptions`** are still showing up in error logs.

What can be the reason?

Comment: Perhaps you should try extending your request timeout to see what that does.

Comment: which kafka version you are using ?

Comment: Sure, will try that. What surprises me is that this a pre-production environment. We have very less load. Not more than 100,000 messages in a day. Is this due to network congestion? Is network getting congested in even such low load?

Comment: @NayanSharma We are using kafka 0.10.0.1

Comment: I am facing the same problem, did you find the reason and a solution?

Answer (score 23):

It is a bit tricky to find the root cause, I'll drop my experience on that, hopefully someone may find it useful. In general it can be a network issue or too much network flood in combination with `ack=ALL`. Here a diagram that explain the `TimeoutException` from [Kafka KIP-91](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-91+Provide+Intuitive+User+Timeouts+in+The+Producer) at he time of writing (still applicable till 1.1.0):

[image]

Excluding network configuration issues or errors, this are the properties you can adjust depending on your scenario in order to mitigate or solve the problem:

- The **buffer.memory** controls the total memory available to a producer for buffering. If records get sent faster than they can be transmitted to Kafka then and this buffer will get exceeded then additional send calls block up to **max.block.ms** after then Producer throws a `TimeoutException`.
- The **max.block.ms** has already a high value and I do not suggest to further increment it. **buffer.memory** has the default value of 32MB and depending on you message size you may want to increase it; if necessary increase the jvm heap space.
- **Retries** define how many attempts to resend the record in case of error before giving up. If you are using zero retries you can try to mitigate the problem by increasing this value, beware record order is not guarantee anymore unless you set **max.in.flight.requests.per.connection** to 1.
- Records are sent as soon as the batch size is reached or the linger time is passed, whichever comes first. if **batch.size** (default 16kb) is smaller than the maximum request size perhaps you should use a higher value. In addition, change **linger.ms** to a higher value such as 10, 50 or 100 to optimize the use of the batch and the compression. This will cause less flood in the network and optimize compression if you are using it.

There is not an exact answer on this kind of issues since they depends also on the implementation, in my case experimenting with the values above helped.

Answer (score 11):

We have faced similar problem. Many `NetworkExceptions` in the logs and from time to time `TimeoutException`.

**Cause**

Once we gathered TCP logs from production it turned out that some of the TCP connections to Kafka brokers (we have 3 broker nodes) were dropped without notifying clients after like 5 minutes of being idle (no `FIN` flags on TCP layer). When client was trying to re-use this connection after that time, then `RST` flag was returned. We could easily match those connections resets in TCP logs with `NetworkExceptions` in application logs.

As for `TimeoutException`, we could not do the same matching as by the time we found the cause, this type of error was not occurring anymore. However we confirmed in a separate test that dropping TCP connection could also result in `TimeoutException`. I guess this is because of the fact that Java Kafka Client is using Java NIO Socket Channel under the hood. All the messages are being buffered and then dispatched once connection is ready. If connection will not be ready within timeout (30 seconds), then messages will expire resulting in `TimeoutException`.

**Solution**

For us the fix was to reduce **connections.max.idle.ms** on our clients to 4 minutes. Once we applied it, `NetworkExceptions` were gone from our logs.

We are still investigating what is dropping the connections.

**Edit**

The cause of the problem was AWS NAT Gateway which was dropping outgoing connections after 350 seconds.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/nat-gateway-troubleshooting.html#nat-gateway-troubleshooting-timeout

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

Modify

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://hostname:9092
```

property in the server.properties file to

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
```

**Solution 2**

Change the broker.id to a value like 1001, change the brocker id by setting the environment variable `KAFKA_BROKER_ID` .

You'll have to set the environment variable `KAFKA_RESERVED_BROKER_MAX_ID` to omething like 1001 to be allowed to set the broker id to 1001.

I hope it can help

Comment: I dont think solution1 can work. I changed to 0.0.0.0 in broker settings now producer clients don't work because server is bind on 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Increment the **request.timeout.ms** and **retries** of your producer