# How can I read faster from Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, producer-consumer, consumer

I created a new Kafka server (I created 1 broker with 1 partition) and I succeeded to produce and consume from this server using java code, but Im not satisfied from the amount of events that I'm reading per second as a consumer.

I have already played with the following consumer setting:

```
AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG = "earliest"
FETCH_MAX_BYTES_CONFIG = 52428800
MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG = 1048576
MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG = 10000
pollDuration = 3000
```

But no matter what I entered as a value to each one of the setting, the result stayed the same

Currently, I produced 100,000 messages to Kafka.
each message size is 2 kilobytes and it took 20669 milliseconds or 20 seconds (total time) to read all batches of 100000 records, which means 5000 records per second.

I expect it to be much higher, what are the most ideal values ​​that I can set or maybe I need to use other setting or maybe I need to set my Kafka server otherwise (multiple brokers or partitions)?

Comment: Add more topics. Add more partitions. Ensure you are running multiple concurrent consumers with a decent ratio to the number of partitions (not necessarily 1:1 but equally don't have 100 partitions and one reader). Check for bottlenecks e.g. network, disk etc. Perhaps you need to spread your partitions across multiple disks and/or have clustered kafka setup.

edit: I wouldn't be surprised if this thread gets deleted since it's a just 'make it faster' which isn't really a problem

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) so in fact you are saying that the consumer setting has nothing to do with the performance issue. Further to your answer, I thought maybe to activate multiple consumer instances (using multi thread in java), and each thread will read from different partition, meaning different group id. is that something that you think should work? and why do you think it will be deleted? its  a performance problem you can say

Comment: for the last part - it's a bit generic and a bit of a RTFM.
Anyway - yes your consumers should read from a different partition automatically (depending on how it's accessed). It gets into trickier realms though when you're talking about 'performance for example, your partitions may be top heavy (e.g. not evenly distributed). Your bottlenecks could be for multiple reasons (again, it might be slow because the writes are hammering it). It's not necessarily a one size fits all and can take months to hit upon a solutions that meets your requirements.

Comment: AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG will read from message 0 (provided it's not been removed), so might not be the behavior you want - perhaps LATEST is best (again it's as per your requirements though).
Look at how you're accessing the kafka instance (through a connector?) is there any contention. If your writes are keeping up I'd say that the issue is with your consumer only though (for now).

Comment: Ok, at least I have a direction now Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the settings you mentioned and ignoring horizontal scaling/partitioning:

if you are not using compression, do it!

From the wiki:

> If enabled, data will be compressed by the producer, written in
>   compressed format on the server and decompressed by the consumer.

`lz4` compression type proved to be a good one in my experience, sample settings for the producer:

```
compression.type = lz4
batch.size = 131072
linger.ms = 10
```

That means less data has to be transmitted in the network and on the other hand more cpu usage for compression/decompression.

you can find more info related to the batch and linger time in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50097286/3224238) other answer I gave related to timeouts, however it is focused on the producer part.

Comment: Great advice! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

from a fundamental point of view - kafka clients maintain a single socket per "broker of interest" (==any broker that leads a topic partition they care about).
over this socket kafka will only do a single request/response at a time (there's a producer setting for max.in.flight.requests.per.connection but the broker only ever serves one at a time).
that means that, by and large, if you want more bandwidth you need more sockets and bigger requests. this means multiple brokers and/or multiple clients, and definitely more than a single partition.
as for things you can tune for your case (single client, single partition, single socket):

```
FETCH_MAX_BYTES_CONFIG = 52428800
MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG = 1048576
```

youre setting the max size of response overall to 50MB, yet limiting the size of data from any specific partition in that same response to 1MB. in your case (1 partition) that means your max response size is effectively 1MB. bump it up.

as stated in other answers, you can enable compression for your topic (on the producer side ideally, though the brokers can be configured to "transcode"), and you can also play around with other less-impactful parameters like check.crcs and receive.buffer.bytes

for a complete list of consumer configs - see https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs

Comment: so if I understand currently, I should set the MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG at least as the FETCH_MAX_BYTES_CONFIG if not much more. am I right?

Comment: i dont think `MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG > FETCH_MAX_BYTES_CONFIG` gets you anything extra, but i usually recommend people set both to the same value.

Comment: Ok great! Thank you for the help!